# Hibernate freeze when insert a lot operations in the same time

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I tried to test my application, I did a lot request (100 per second) to my server. In this request, app does select, insert and update. And I have some dead lock there. But behavior of application is very weird.

It does inserts in amount of my pool size and just freeze. Does not throw any exception etc. Seems that it try update the same column and get deadlock.
I think except reason of deadlock I have wrong configuration of `hibernate` and `datasource`. So it is my properties:

**persistence.xml**

```html
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">
 <persistence-unit name="InspectionPersistenceUnit"
  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <properties>
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="50" />
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="30" />
   <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="10" /> 
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" /> 
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="UTF-8" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding"
    value="UTF-8" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**applicationContext**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:data="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
 xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.8.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-2.0.xsd">


 <bean id="jdbcPropertyConfigurer"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
  p:location="classpath:config.properties" />

 <security:global-method-security
  secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true"
  pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.ripplehouse.gw" />
 <context:annotation-config />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <tx:annotation-driven />

 <data:repositories base-package="com.ripplehouse.gw" />

 

 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="${datasource.driver.class.name}" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${datasource.url}" />
  <property name="user" value="${datasource.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
 </bean>


 <bean
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
  id="entityManagerFactory">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="InspectionPersistenceUnit" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
  id="transactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Does your database allow 50 connections?